# Is there a way to add an OnSuccess script to my Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Switch/showOptions',
    data: {
        switchid: "331",

    },
    type: 'get',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#showoptions').html(html);
        $("#showoptions").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
        OnSuccess('createsuccess')         
    },
});
```

What I am trying to do is to fire an `OnSuccess` script after showing the dialog, currently I am getting an exception that OnSuccess is not defined? So can anyone advice how I can fire an `OnSuccess` script for my Ajax call?

Comment: WHat do you mean `OnSuccess` - you're already using the `success` callback?

Comment: what is `OnSuccess`? Is it a function somewhere? where is it defined, can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Is it as simple as creating a function and calling it, was that your question?

Comment: Can you show us how you've declared OnSuccess()?

Comment: when i use Ajax helpers inside asp.net mvc i have an option to define functions such as Onsuccess , OnComplete,Onfailure , etc. so i am trying to achive the same here..

Comment: the sucess in my case will update the div with the returned html, but i want to fire a script after updating the div with the html, the script will display a confirmation message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) as described [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184759/ajax-call-function-after-success#6185021):

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

So with that in mind, here is your code reworked to use `jQuery.when()`:

```
var ajax_action = $.ajax({
    url: '/Switch/showOptions',
    data: {
        switchid: "331",

    },
    type: 'get',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#showoptions').html(html);
        $("#showoptions").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
    },
});

$.when(ajax_action).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { OnSuccess('createsuccess'); });
```

Or if you just want to test this concept, change the `jQuery.when()` to be this:

```
$.when(ajax_action).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('I am a success!'); });
```

**EDIT:** Last edit to try and address original posters request. They want to fire a script called `createsuccess`, so just do this:

```
$.when(ajax_action).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { createsuccess(); });
```

Comment: still i am getting the following exception 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'OnSuccess' is undefined

Comment: i used to work with ajax.actionlinks and ajax.beginforms , which are ajax helpers used by the asp.net mvc . where inside the ajax.actionlink i can define an onsuccess script that fires when the ajaxcall is successful . so i want to have similar script for my ajax call..

Comment: the OnSuccess is nto a function , it means that it will fire a script when the ajax call is success. the script which should fire is "createsuccess " in my case

Comment: thanks for the help , basically this worked for my $.when(ajax_action).then(function(data) { createsuccess(data); });

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if you add a ; after your OnSuccess call. This isn't an event to be fired but it is a a function that will be executed after the first two statements.

```
function OnSuccess(p_Success) {
    alert('it worked!');
}


$.ajax({
    url: '/Switch/showOptions',
    data: {
        switchid: "331",

    },
    type: 'get',
    success: function (html) {
        $('#showoptions').html(html);
        $("#showoptions").dialog("show"); //This could also be dialog("open") depending on the version of jquery ui.
        OnSuccess('createsuccess');
    },
});
```