# Ajax to wait until Api Is done before next function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm a noob with this stuff(so please be patient), All i want to do is execute a function after  the API is completely done, at the moment the JavaScript is posting and reading at the same time giving me unwanted results.

```
        function getData() {
            return $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
            data: JSON.stringify(test), 
            url:"/api/answers/", 
            contentType: "application/json"
```

So I read this article  [jQuery ajax success callback function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition)

and did  this

```
        var timer = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(timer.resolve, 5000);
        var jaax = getData().done();
        $.when(timer, jaax).done(this.Seven());
```

This  doesn't work  since it calls **function** Seven  anyways while its posting

I also tried this
[Ajax call function after success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184759/ajax-call-function-after-success):

```
      $.ajax({ type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(test), 
         url: "/api/answers/", 
         contentType: "application/json" ,
         success: Seven
          } ); }
```

And that just gave my soul pain as it calls **function** Seven while posting, What am i missing? why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
getData().done(function(results){
    // results are what retuned from the server
    Seven();
});
```